# Is it possible to create a dictionary where each value is a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

So, my question may not be that simple, but let's go:

let's say i have a function called `create_a_dataframe()` that i use to create dataframes and looks like this

```
def create_a_dataframe(place_where_data_comes_from)
   data = <gets data from place_where_data_comes_from>
   df = pd.DataFrame(data)
   return df
```

And i need to run this function 5 times, each time the function will return a dataframe that will be stored as a value in a dict:

```
my_5_values = [datasource1, datasource2, datasource3, datasource4, datasource5]
dict_with_dataframes = {}

for datasource in my_5_values:
   dict_with_dataframes[f"datasource name {datasource }"] = create_a_dataframe(datasource)
```

But when I try to show the first dataframe using

`dict_with_dataframes['datasource name datasource1']`

It returns a list with all the 5 keys and values.
Am i doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do `print(f"datasource name {datasource }")`. It is not what you think it is.

`datasource` is just a dataframe value, not the string `"datasource1"`. There is no good way to get a variable name. Instead, explicitly give names:

```
my_5_values = {"datasource1": datasource1,  ... }
dict_with_dataframes = {}

for name, datasource in my_5_values.items():
   dict_with_dataframes[f"datasource name {name}"] = create_a_dataframe(datasource)
```

Comment: I just did that but the result was the same. When i use dict_with_dataframes['datasource1'] the only thing it shows me is the whole dictionary, for some unknown reason

Comment: I can see no reason for that, given the code sample you provided. However, it is not a [example], so I cannot test it. Please create a [example] that exhibits this behaviour — there is nothing further I can say without one.

Comment: That was my fault, Amadan. Sorry. I just fixed a for loop and now it's working fine with your solution. Thanks!